# Graph Help - Circular Barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, plotly

I've no idea where to even start with this. I've looked at GGPlot and plotly etc to try and find the right thing but haven't come across anything.

This is as example of my data though

```
Skill <- c("Tackling", "Shooting", "Technique", "Passing", "Pace", "Stamina")
Grade <- c("A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "B")
data <- data.frame(Skill, Grade)
```

This is the sort of graph I'd like
[image]

I'm a football scout and it would be fantastic to be able to have a graph like that to compare the players we have to the player I'm scouting.

so if the grade is D, it would just show red, if the grade was C it would show red and orange. Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite close to what you want:

```
Skill <- c("Tackling", "Shooting", "Technique", "Passing", "Pace", "Stamina")
Grade <- c("A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "B")
data <- data.frame(Skill, Grade)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data$grade <- factor(data$Grade, levels=c("D","C","B","A"))
data$grade2 <- recode(data$grade, A="B")
data$grade3 <- recode(data$grade2, B="C")
data$grade4 <- recode(data$grade3, C="D")

ggplot(data, aes(x=Skill, y=grade)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="green",col="black",width=1)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=grade2),stat="identity", fill="yellow",col="black",width=1)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=grade3),stat="identity", fill="orange",col="black",width=1)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=grade4),stat="identity", fill="red",col="black",width=1)  + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c("D","C","B","A")) + 
  coord_polar(start = pi/6) + theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much, exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data, aes(Skill, Grade, fill = Grade)) + 
      geom_tile() +
      coord_polar() +
      theme_bw()
```

To have all levels below the grade coded, you'll need to have all those lower levels within the `dataframe`, which is in a way redundant. Wouldn't it be?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've never even had a play around with graphs before on R. so this was definitely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = transform(data, gr = as.numeric(factor(data$Grade, c("D", "C", "B", "A"))))
d = do.call(rbind, lapply(split(d, d$Skill), function(x){
    foo = with(x, setNames(data.frame(Skill[1], Grade[1], seq(gr)), names(x)))
}))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(Skill, gr, fill = factor(gr, 4:1))) +
    geom_col() +
    coord_polar()
```

Comment: This is definetely what I'm looking for, thank you. Aesthetically pleasing.